# Add a row of zeros in a data frame created with ddply if there are no observations

Tags: r, plyr

I used the function `ddply` (package `plyr`) to calculate the mean of a response variable for each group "Trial" and "Treatment". I get this data frame:

```
Trial   Treatment   N   Mean
1           A      458  125.258
1           B      459  168.748
2           A      742  214.266
2           B      142  475.786
3           A      247  145.689
3           B      968  234.129
4           A      436  456.287
```

This data frame suggests that in the trial 4 and treatment B, there are no observations for the response variable (as no row is specified in the data frame). So, is it possible to automatically add a row of zeros in the data frame (built with the function “ddply”) when there are no observations for a given response variable?

I would like to get this data frame:

```
Trial   Treatment   N   Mean
1           A      458  125.258
1           B      459  168.748
2           A      742  214.266
2           B      142  475.786
3           A      247  145.689
3           B      968  234.129
4           A      436  456.287
4           B       0   0
```

Comment: you might try to include `.drop = FALSE` inside `ddply`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can `merge` the original dataset with another data.frame created with the full combination of unique values in 'Trial', and 'Treatment'.  It will give an output with the missing combinations filled with `NA`.  If needed, this can be changed to 0 (but it is better to have the missing combination as NA).

```
res <- merge(expand.grid(lapply(df1[1:2], unique)), df1, all.x=TRUE)
is.na(res) <- res==0
```

---

Or with `dplyr/tidyr`, we can use `complete` (from `tidyr`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   complete(Trial, Treatment, fill= list(N=0, Mean=0))
#  Trial Treatment     N    Mean
#  (int)     (chr) (dbl)   (dbl)
#1     1         A   458 125.258
#2     1         B   459 168.748
#3     2         A   742 214.266
#4     2         B   142 475.786
#5     3         A   247 145.689
#6     3         B   968 234.129
#7     4         A   436 456.287
#8     4         B     0   0.000
```